# Cannot access connection string in app.config by using c#

Tags: c#

App.config file configuration 1

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
        <configuration>
          <connectionStrings>
            <add name="MyDBConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=223.29.207.133;
                 Initial Catalog=MBV5DBLive;User ID=smsuser;Password=sms;IntegratedSecurity=true"
                 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
          </connectionStrings>
        </configuration>
```

App.config file configuration 2

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDBConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;
         Initial Catalog=University;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>


C# code



 try
                    {
                        String constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

                        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
                        {
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
```

even if i debug when it comes to configuration manager code will jump to catch block and it will show "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
What is the issue with above both configuration files?

Comment: The name is `c_str` not `MyDBConnectionString`

Comment: By any chance is this connection string in an app.config within a data project, but you are accessing this code through a different front end?

Answer (score 3):

Your connection string name seems like `c_str` not `MyDBConnectionString`.

And since you don't have *any* `MyDBConnectionString` in your web config, your `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDBConnectionString"]` returns `null` and that's why you get `NullReferenceException` when you try to access `ConnectionString` property of a `null` reference.

If everything is okey other than that, this should work;

```
var constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["c_str"].ConnectionString;
using (var con = new SqlConnection(constring))
{
}
```